Mass attenuation coefficient for sr90 beta radiation in water
I'm looking for either the mass attenuation coefficient or linear attenuation coefficient for sr90 beta radiation (or generally 0.546 MeV beta radiation - Yttrium decay and radiation can be ignored in this context) in water. Ideally with a reputable, non-paywalled reference.
I didn't have much luck googling this, at least for non-paywalled information, so asking here. I could find reasonable information for X-ray attenuation in water, but I assume even for similar energy levels, due to the different type of radiation, the values are not the same?

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Electron-range-in-liquid-water-The-calculations-have-been-performed_fig11_230924859#:~:text=In%20comparison%20to%20this%20value,50%20MeV%20to%20300%20MeV.

Not quite an answer, but from https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/beta-particle "The range of beta particles in air is ∼4 m per MeV of energy. In water the range in cm is approximately one-half the maximum beta energy when expressed in MeV."

For the Op, note that is the range of the electron. Any X-rays generated will, of course, go further.

Thanks for your comments. I do actually need the attenuation coefficient not just the range. The background is an experiment that measured the amount of radiation after passing through various depths of water. This was used to derive a coefficient by fitting an exponential curve and the next step would be to compare that value to the generally accepted value. It seems very hard though to find that value in the literature though.
